# Matplotlib - how to combine a list of AxesSubplot into one figure with multiple subplots?

Tags: matplotlib

I have generated a list of matplotlib AxesSubplot object and I would like to combine them into one figure with a subplot for each AxesSubplot object.
Let's say I have 9 AxesSubplot object stored in a python list called "axlist" and I want to display them together in a 3x3 grid:

```
def random_figure_generator(n):
    """
    Create n random plots
    """
    axlist = list()
    for i in range(n):
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
        x = sorted(np.random.random(100))
        ax.plot(np.linspace(0,100,100), np.random.random(100))
        plt.show(fig)
        plt.close(fig)
        axlist.append(ax)
    return axlist

#Create a list of axes object 
axlist = random_figure_generator(9)

#Attempt to combine them
axes = []
fig, axes = plt.subplots(3,3)
axes = axes.flatten()
for i in range(len(axlist)):
    axes[i].axes = axlist[i] #try to assign each AxesSubplot object to one subplot in the new figure
plt.show()
```

And here is what I get:
[Figure with 3x3 subplots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5PDJ.png)

Comment: This is not useful. Better create the plot inside the figure which should contain the plot.

Comment: It is indeed easier to create the plots inside the figure, but I need to look at individual plots earlier in my analysis and wanted to reuse them instead of recreating all the plots a second time.

Comment: Any solution of "moving" axes around between figures is much more brittle and a lot more complicated, than just using a function which can be reused to draw the same plot on several axes.